# unable to set prop on nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS and using this library https://github.com/salesforce/design-system-react.

I'm attempting to use a component I created `SelectCell`. It's being used two times. I'd like to pass it a prop `selectedOption` and in the first instance pass it a property originating from my state, a property `selectedSectionId` and the second time the component is used set `selectedOption` to be `selectedQuestionId`.

The issue is the library obfuscates some of the logic away and I'm not well versed enough in react to understand what to do. I set `items` on the `DataTable` component and I know the children components have access to `item` in props. I'm getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedSectionId' of undefined` My component is below:

```
import React from 'react';

import {Button,DataTable,DataTableColumn,DataTableCell,Dropdown,DataTableRowActions} from '@salesforce/design-system-react';

const ParameterDataTableCell = ({ children, ...props }) => (
    <DataTableCell title={children} {...props}>
        <input type='text' className='slds-input' value={props.item.parameterName} />
    </DataTableCell>
);
ParameterDataTableCell.displayName = DataTableCell.displayName;

const SelectCell = ({ children,...props }) => (

    <DataTableCell {...props}>
        <div>
            <Dropdown
                align='left'
                checkmark={false}
                iconCategory='utility'
                iconName='down'
                iconPosition='right'
                label={setPicklistLabel(props.allOptions,props.type,props.item,props.selectedOptionId)}
                options={props.allOptions}
                value={props.item.sectionName}>
            </Dropdown>
        </div>
    </DataTableCell>
);

const setPicklistLabel = (allOptions,picklistType,item,selectedOptionId) => {
    const foundOption = allOptions.find((thisOption) => selectedOptionId===thisOption.id);
    return foundOption ? foundOption.label : 'Select an Option';
}

SelectCell.displayName = DataTableCell.displayName;

class ParameterTable extends React.Component {
    static displayName = 'ParameterTable';
    state = {
        paramRows: [
            {
                parameterName: 'param1',
                selectedSectionId: '001441094',
                selectedQuestionId: '00ri23or231441094'
                
            },
            {
                parameterName: 'param2',
                selectedSectionId: '001441094',
                selectedQuestionId: '00ri23or231441094'
            }
        ],
    };

    addRow = () => {
        const newRow = {'parameterName':'','selectedSectionId':'','selectedQuestionId':''};
        const rows = this.state.paramRows;
        rows.push(newRow);
        this.setState({items:rows});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DataTable
                    items={this.state.paramRows}
                    className='slds-m-top_large'
                >
                    <DataTableColumn
                        label='Parameter Name'
                        primaryColumn
                        property='parameterName'
                        
                    >
                        <ParameterDataTableCell />
                    </DataTableColumn>
                    <DataTableColumn
                        label='Section Name'
                        property='sectionName'
                    >
                        <SelectCell 
                            allOptions={this.props.serverData.allSections}
                            selectedOptionId={this.props.item.selectedSectionId}/>
                    </DataTableColumn>
                    <DataTableColumn
                        label='Question Name'
                        property='questionName'
                    >
                        <SelectCell 
                            allOptions={this.props.serverData.allQuestions}
                            selectedOptionId={this.props.item.selectedQuestionId}/>
                    </DataTableColumn>
                </DataTable>
                <Button
                        iconCategory='utility'
                        iconName='add'
                        iconPosition='right'
                        label='Add Parameter'
                        onClick={this.addRow}
                    />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ParameterTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, from first glance, it seems like you missed out using the `constructor(props)` and `super(props)` lines.

```
class ParameterTable extends React.Component {
    static displayName = 'ParameterTable';
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          paramRows: [
              {
                  parameterName: 'param1',
                  selectedSectionId: '001441094',
                  selectedQuestionId: '00ri23or231441094'
                
              },
              {
                  parameterName: 'param2',
                  selectedSectionId: '001441094',
                  selectedQuestionId: '00ri23or231441094'
              }
          ],
      };
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated it but still getting the same error.

Comment: In this case, it most likely means you are trying to access `selectedSectionId ` before `this.props.item` is initialized. How are the `props` passed into the `ParameterTable` class?

Comment: `this.props.item` is the part I'm a little unclear on. I set `items` on the `DataTable` component above, and its available in the `SelectCell` component. I think its part of the library, you never actually see a .map() iterate through `items` in my code.

Comment: I see what you mean. So the error is thrown from `<DataTable />`?

Comment: Error is on this line `selectedOptionId={this.props.item.selectedSectionId}/>`, it thinks `this.props.item` is `undefined` even though this line `label={setPicklistLabel(props.allOptions,props.type,props.item,props.selectedOptionId)}`has `props.item` defined, it may just be me not understanding how react works correctly.

Comment: I think the first issue is that `this.props` cannot be accessed inside `<ParameterTable  />`. You can verify by `console.log`-ing `this.props.` inside the  class. That's the logical explanation for the error. Try that first.